# How to set a default value for enum class for Pydantic/FastAPI

Tags: python, enums, fastapi, pydantic

I was trying to find a way to set a default value for `Enum` class on Pydantic as well as FastAPI docs but I couldn't find how to do this. Here is my enum class:

```
class ConnectionStatus(str,Enum):
    active:"active"
    inactive:"inactive"
    deprecated:"deprecated"
```

And I'd like to make `active` as default, for example.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your enum class has some syntax error, it should be ***`=`*** instead of ***`:`***. Thus, your ***`ConnectionStatus`*** will become,

```
class ConnectionStatus(str, Enum):
    active = 'active'
    inactive = 'inactive'
    deprecated = 'deprecated'
```

and to set the default value, use the below snippet

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from enum import Enum

app = FastAPI()


class ConnectionStatus(str, Enum):
    active = 'active'
    inactive = 'inactive'
    deprecated = 'deprecated'


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    status: ConnectionStatus = ConnectionStatus.active


@app.post("/")
async def some_route(data: SomeModel):
    return data
```

Reference: [Enums and Choices - Pydantic Doc](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#enums-and-choices)

Comment: I am using this example but I get a 422 Unprocesable Entity

Comment: Is it possible to allow null in the request body and still have a non-null default value so that the caller doesn't have to send the value but the server will receive the default value in request body?

Comment: Here, the default value will be picked from enum class ***in the absence of a field in the request body***. If you want to update the logic, you may need to do it manually by writing your logic @AbhishekDalvi

Comment: When using this example, mypy raises an error [Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "ConnectionStatus") any idea on how to solve this ?